# Golang mongodb driver error schema validation

Tags: mongodb, validation, go

I'm writing a little REST API with golang and [mongodb official driver](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo) I'm stuck with error validation from mongodb.

Let me explain :

**My Validation Schema (simplified)**

```
var jsonSchema = bson.M{
    "bsonType":             "object",
    "required":             []string{"lastname"},
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": bson.M{
        "lastname": bson.M{
            "bsonType":    "string",
            "description": "must be a string and is required",
        },
    },
}

var validator = bson.M{
    "$jsonSchema": jsonSchema,
}

// Migrate create users collection with validation schema
func (r *Repo) Migrate() error {

    opts := options.CreateCollection().SetValidator(validator)

    if err := r.db.CreateCollection(r.ctx, "users", opts); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

So in my validation schema I required user lastname and give it a description to handle error with it (I understand that from documentation)

But with my create user func :

```
// Create user to repo
func (r *Repo) Create(usr *User) {
    if r.err != nil {
        return
    }
    u := r.db.Collection("users")
    _, err := u.InsertOne(r.ctx, usr)
    if err != nil {
        we, ok := err.(mongo.WriteException)
        if ok {
            fmt.Println(we)

            for _, r := range we.WriteErrors {
                fmt.Println(r)
            }

        }
        r.err = fmt.Errorf("error occured during creating. got=%w", err)
        return
    }
}
```

and my user struct

```
// User structure representation
type User struct {
    ID        primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    Lastname  string             `bson:"lastname"`
}
```

My json body from post http request

```
{
  "something": "xxxx"
}
```

error expected:
something like (exemple what I expected to have as error):

```
{
    "field": "lastname",
    "message": "must be a string and is required"
}
```

I got from my err :
`multiple write errors: [{write errors: [{Document failed validation}]}, {<nil>}]`

And from my err cast to WriteException:
`Document failed validation`

I read [from documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#available-keywords)
`description    N/A string  A string that describes the schema and has no effect.`
But has no effect to validate or it's just as a comment for someone read schema?

I'd like to have my description about my error to display it to my http resp !
Maybe I'm in the wrong way to manage it so I'm ok to rewrite it !

Thank to read me and hope someone can help me with that :)
Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (MongoDB v4.4) the reason for document validation failure is not returned back by the MongoDB server. There is an open issue [SERVER-20547](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20547) to track this work. Please feel free to watch or up-vote the ticket to receive progress update.

You should implement an application level input validation. Ensuring that the inputs are in the correct data types before database insertion.

Comment: Yes thank you, I did a struct validation before insert to db. I'll follow this issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tool to create schemas from you golang structs
https://github.com/s-augustovitko/mongo-schema-go

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the id field in the properties because the `additionalProperties` attribute was set to false. Mongodb automatically injects the **_id** field into the document that will be inserted into the collection, for data processing performance.

Below is the example of the scheme you are using added to the **_id** property:

```golang
var jsonSchema = bson.M{
    "bsonType":             "object",
    "required":             []string{"lastname"},
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": bson.M{
        "_id": bson.M{
            "bsonType": "objectId",
        },
        "lastname": bson.M{
            "bsonType":    "string",
            "description": "must be a string and is required",
        },
    },
}
```